# Probability of Winning on any turn.

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

Let arbitrary integer $k$ be the total number of turns, and integer $j$ refer to a specific turn out of those $k$ turns.

If the probability of winning on a turn is $1/16$, how can I express the probability of winning on any of the turns in terms of $k$ and $j$?

Is there any kind of formula or distribution that works for this?

Comment: Do you mean that you have $k > j$ items and you want to find the probability of winning on the first, second, third, etc. up to the $j^\text{th}$ term?

Comment: Yes, that's right.

Comment: So it's simply the probability of winning within $k$ turns.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are saying, that winning is the first turn that you win, the this is the probability of losing on j-1 turns times the probability of winning on the jth turn.  This is (15/16)^(j-1) × 1/16.

If winning is winning on any turn from 1 to k, $$\sum_{j=1}^k (15/16)^{(j-1)}*1/16$$,  this is because winning on any one term is an element of a partition of the probability space, so you can sum the term I gave for the first answer.

Comment: So, its sort of like that, but more like the probability of winning on any of the j's in k. So P(winning on j) + P(winning on j-1) + . . . through all of k expressed in terms of both k and j

Answer (score 0):

This probability creates a geometric series.  The probability of winning on the first turn is $\frac{1}{16}$.  The probability of winning on the second turn is $\frac{1}{16}\cdot \frac{15}{16}$, on the third turn, $\frac{1}{16}\left(\frac{15}{16}\right)^2$.  So the probability of winning in $k$ turns is the sum of the probability of winning in the first, second, third, etc. up to $k$:

$$
p(k) = \frac{1}{16}\sum_0^{k - 1}\left(\frac{15}{16}\right)^j
$$

Using the [summation formula for a geometric series](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/GeometricSeries.html) this is:

\begin{align}
\require{cancel}
p(x)=&\ \frac{1}{16}\cdot \frac{1 - \left(\frac{15}{16}\right)^k}{1 - \frac{15}{16}}\\
=&\ \frac{1}{\cancel{16}}\frac{16^k - 15^k }{16-15}\cdot \frac{\cancel{16}}{16^k} \\
=&\ 1 - \left(\frac{15}{16}\right)^k
\end{align}

This result shouldn't be surprising since the probability of not winning in the first $k$ is the probability of losing all $k$.